# Laravel accessor relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have relationship batch and project

```js
function project(){
 return $this->hasMany(Project::class,'batch_id');
}
```

I need to get which batch is complete based on all projects (status = COMPLETED) as a Laravel accessor in model.

this is my sample data

[image]

please help. thanks!

Comment: What's your question about this?

Comment: add `->where('status', 'completed')->get()` to your query

Comment: @NicoHaase i want to get where bacth is complete (true or false)

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all information. Also, share more details and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @xNoJustice it still get bacth that project still not complete

Comment: I think you have a typo in your relationship definition, shouldn't `bacth_id` be `batch_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

#### In the Relationship

You can add the where inline on the relationship

```php
function project(){ 
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class,"bacth_id")->where("status","COMPLETED");
}
```

#### When Invoking the Relationship

If you want to keep the relationship without the where and only use it sometimes, you can call the relationship and add the where. for example, if you have an instance of your model (im going to call it $model in this example) you can do the following, notice the parenthesis next to the relationship name:

```php
$completed = $model->project()->where("status","COMPLETED")->get();
```

#### In a Query

If you are writing a query where you are trying to pull in only versions of that model where the project is complete you can use the ***whereHas*** function. as i dont know what your model is called in your example, im just gonna call it Model

```php
$posts = Model::whereHas("project", function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where("status","COMPLETED");
})->get();
```

Comment: does it get the batch where all project completed?
and how to pass a value to true or false ?

Comment: I just edit my question. I need to get bacth where all project completed.

Comment: yes, this does exactly that, if you want all the batch where the project is complete then you need to use the "In a Query" option above. replacing the word "Model" with your model class. it will return all of the models linked to a complete project where the "status" field has a value of "COMPLETED", as this is a text field there is no need to pass a boolean anywhere

Comment: If you need to get the opposite where all values are not completed then you can change the where statement to ->where(”status”, "!=", "COMPLETED");

Comment: I just fixed a couple of typos in the "In a Query" example

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code from

```
function project(){
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class,'batch_id');
     }
```

to

```
function project(){
       return $this->hasMany(Project::class,'project_id');
       }
```

to get the completed batch

```
$batch=Project::where('status','COMPLETED')->pluck('batch_id');
```